# What's best way to fetch data from web service and then store in SQLite database?

Tags: json, windows-8, windows-runtime, microsoft-metro, background-process

I am developing a Windows Store app. It daily downloads some data via web service as JSON and then do some parsing to JSON and then it stores in database. This all operation may take 5 minutes to 1 hour depending upon size of data in JSON response. Now when app is doing operation and user switch the app, it goes in suspended state and hence the data fetching & storing stops. So what would be the best way to fetch & store data in background, so if user switches the app the data fetching & storing will work like in running state of app ?

Comment: have you tried BackgroundTransfer (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh452975.aspx) ??

Comment: It's for download/upload file. I am calling web service with [`HttpClient`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh138077.aspx)